# BackboneJS + Codeigniter - RESTful API - How to create one single big API?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I have a Backbone application where use Codeigniter as backend. Now, to display data from my Database i use the RESTful API to get the data and pass it as JSON to Backbone. The data I want to fetch are Bandnames from A-Z and its always the same data: band_id and band_name. So for that purpose I want to create one single Backbone Model which should tell the Collections what data to handle. So in my Codeigniter setup, in the `application`-folder->`controllers`-folder I created an `api`-folder, where I created an `artist.php`-file, which basically looks like this:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class artists extends REST_Controller{

// BANDS WITH LETTER A
public function a_get()  
{ 
 $this->load->database();
 $sql = "SELECT band_id, band_name FROM `bands` WHERE bands_name LIKE 'A%' LIMIT 100";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
 $data = $query->result();

 if($data) {
    $this->response($data, 200);
 } else {
    $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter a!'), 404);
 }
}  

public function a_put()  
{  
// Update
}  

public function a_post()  
{  
// Post/insert
}  

public function a_delete()  
{  
// delete
}

// BANDS WITH LETTER B
public function b_get()  
{ 
 $this->load->database();
 $sql = "SELECT band_id, band_name FROM `bands` WHERE band_name LIKE 'B%' LIMIT 10";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
 $data = $query->result();

 if($data) {
    $this->response($data, 200);
 } else {
    $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter b!'), 404);
 }
}  

public function b_put()  
{  
// Update
}  

public function b_post()  
{  
// Post/insert
}  

public function b_delete()  
{  
// delete
}
... LETTER C code
... LETTED D code etc. etc.
?>
```

My Backbone Model would look like this:

```
function($, Backbone) {
var BandModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "../myproejct/index.php/api/bands/",

    defaults: {
        "band_id": ' ',
        "band_name": ' '
    }
});

return BandModel;
});
```

And a collection would look like this:

```
function(Backbone, BandModel) {
var BandCollectionA = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BandModel,
    url: "../myproject/index.php/api/bands/a"
});

return BandCollectionA;
});
```

So my question is: can I do it like this? Can I do the API, the `artists.php`, like that? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter support sub folder in controller so you can organize them like you describe.

Otherwise you can consider a HMVC for CodeIgnter. This is [HMVC](https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-hmvc-modules) alternative but you can find other on web.

Here is the link if you have trouble and want a good tutorial of REST service in CodeIgniter: [Tuts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2--net-8814)